# Java Front Controller

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, front-controller

I'm thinking of implementing Front Controller in my J2EE application. Could you please suggest the same with few links (with source code examples) & any standards to follow?

Best regards

Comment: How about the Spring MVC framework?  
http://www.springsource.org/

Comment: J2EE is replaced by Java EE since more than 3 years. Keep yourself updated.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I generally go with that ... anyways thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To start, create a `Servlet` which listens on a certain `url-pattern`, e.g. `/pages/*`. Implement the `service()` method to lookup the action associated with the request method (`GET`, `POST`, etc) and pathinfo (the URL part after the servlet's `url-pattern`).

Basic example:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
  throws ServletException, IOException {
  View view = new View(request, response);
  Action action = ActionFactory.getAction(request);
  action.execute(view);
  view.navigate();
}
```

The `Action` interface should represent an unit of work. You can implement it to do the necessary business logic:

```
public interface Action {
  void execute(View view);
}
```

The `ActionFactory` should maintain the classes implementing `Action` in sort of `Map<String, Action>` where the `String` key represents less or more a combination of the request method and pathinfo. You could then get an `Action` as follows:

```
public static Action getAction(HttpServletRequest request) {
  return actions.get(request.getMethod() + request.getPathInfo());
}
```

The `View` should represent the request scoped context which the `Action` can work with. In the `navigate()` you could forward the request to a JSP for display:

```
public void navigate() {
  String path = "/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo() + ".jsp";
  request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
}
```

That should get you started (note that I left all obvious checks such as null pointers away to make the examples less cluttered, that's up to you now).

There is however more to take account with in the whole story, such as validation, conversion, event handling, input value mappings, localization, dependency injection, etcetera. That's all with all quite a work. The more decent MVC frameworks takes most of this all into account, such as [Sun JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html), [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/kickstart.html), [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html), [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home), etcetera. If you have never done any of them, then I strongly recommend to do so before homegrowing one, otherwise you would end up with a waste of time.

Comment: When I read these documentation about Spring MVC, it always talks about Servlet engine to be Tomcat. Does it make any different if my servlet engine is Glassfish? Does glassfish read the content of web.xml?

Comment: @Harry: Spring is a bit anti-Sun.

Comment: @Harry: I didn't mean to say that Spring won't work on GF. It will work as good.

Comment: @BalusC would be nice if you extend your answer with an example of `action.execute()`, where you would explain how the controller passes data/helper to the view via `request.setAttribute()`. I think that it's an important concept to show..

Comment: @yegor: a more detailed answer is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297 This does however not abstract the request/response away in a facade class. But to the point you can just let it delegate. See also how the `Context` is described at bottom of the linked answer. The example in the answer above is a bit bare :)

Answer (score 1):

The web is full of mature java web frameworks. I can't see a reason to create a new one with two exceptions: 1. You have some very non-standard environment/flow and need something very, very specific to your needs. 2. You simply want to go through the exercise of creating a framework to learn about the ins and outs of httpservlet development.

JSR 154 defines the servlet specs. Find it here: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=154

Spring is one of the current popular frameworks and the one that works for me. Struts was one of the first very popular frameworks that has started to decline in popularity. Find a good list of frameworks along with discussion at http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks