# How to develop JSP/Servlets Web App using MVC pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I'm developing a JSP/Servlet web app (no frameworks). I want to use **MVC** pattern. I am going to design my project like this:

1. **Controller**: a servlet that reads a request, extracts the values,communicates with model objects and  gives information to a JSP page.
2. **View**: JSP Pages.
3. **Model**: Java Classes / Java Beans .. etc.

**The problem:**  `Index.jsp` is the starting point (default page) in my web site. So, the `Index.jsp` becomes the controller to parse the request. For example, the following request:

```
index.jsp?section=article&id=10
```

is parsed in index.jsp as following :

```
<div class="midcol">
<!-- Which section? -->
<%String fileName = request.getParameter("section");
if (fileName == null) {
fileName = "WEB-INF/jspf/frontpage.jsp";
} else {
fileName = "WEB-INF/jspf/" + fileName + ".jsp";
}
%>
<jsp:include page='<%= fileName%>' />
</div>
```

Here, I can't force the servlet to be a controller, because the `index.jsp` is the controller here since it's the starting point.

Is there any solution to forward the request from `index.jsp` to the servlet and then go back to `index.jsp`? Or any solution that achieves the **MVC** goal - the servlet should be the controller?

I'm thinking of making a **FrontPageController servlet** as default page instead of **index.jsp**, but I don't know if it's a perfect idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get rid of `index.jsp` and just let the controller servlet listen on a specific `url-pattern` of interest. The controller itself should forward the request to the JSP page of interest using `RequestDispatcher`.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Alternatively you can let `index.jsp` forward or redirect to an URL which is covered by the controller servlet which in turn shows the "default" page (which seems to be `frontpage.jsp`).

That said, in a correct MVC approach, you should have **no** *scriptlets* in JSP files. Whenever you need to write some raw Java code inside a JSP file which can't be replaced reasonably by taglibs ([JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) and so on) or EL, then the particular Java code belongs in any way in a real Java class, like a Servlet, Filter, Javabean, etcetera.

With regard to the homegrown MVC approach, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060128/java-front-controller/2060842#2060842) and [this article](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/frontman.html) useful as well.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Did you mean by the first paragraph that the front page in my website should be a servlet such as : /default-servlet ? Should I do something to make "default-servlet" the default page when someone visits my website and enter just the domain xyz.com/?

Comment: If you want a real `welcome-file`, then you can keep the `index.jsp`, but instead let it forward or redirect to the desired default page. The `welcome-file` unfortunately can't be a servlet. This point should at least be clear: the controller logic as you wrote in the JSP doesn't belong in the JSP. It belongs in the servlet.