# how to create mvc based application without using framework

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Struts, Spring and a few other frameworks implement the MVC architecture to separate the representation of information from the user's interaction with it.

Can any one explain or give me a link for that in Java EE?

Without using a framework, how can I create an MVC application and what are the design patterns needed for that?

Comment: Reading this [**thread**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575471/how-to-develop-jsp-servlets-web-app-using-mvc-pattern) and this [**link**](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp) might help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this presentation](http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/csajsp2/14-MVC.pdf), which is part of [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) on http://www.coreservlets.com/

Answer (score 3):

you can use Servlet and Jsp to create a MVC application without using any framework,

here are some useful links,
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/72183-mvc-application-in-java/

another useful example,

http://css.dzone.com/articles/web-mvc-java

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good tutorial on [Creating MVC architecture with servlets and jsp](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/)

The main concern in creating MVC architecture is the separation of concerns. You need to separate business layer, presentation layer and controler layer

- Model layer is achieved by simple POJO
- View layer i.e. Presentation layer can be achieved by JSP
- Controllers can be achieved by servlets in java ee

Answer (score 1):

You can use Servlets and JSP directly.
For managing Java EE applications we are using design patterns.

MVC-1 and MVC-2 are design patterns for managing the UI layer.
Struts and Spring-MVC are implementations of the MVC-2 design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**MVC** stands for Model View and Controller.  It is a design pattern that separates the business logic, presentation logic and data.

- **Controller** acts as an interface between View and Model. Controller intercepts all the requests.
- **Model** represents the state of the application i.e. data.
- **View** represents the presentaion.

This [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp) contains an example to implement it with JSP and Servelet.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you first question: the part of the Java EE framework that implements MVC is called JSF. This provides templates, graphical components (widgets) and much more.

To answer your second question: you don't really build an MVC app without any framework. You may be using Servlets and JSP, but that too is a framework. Java EE in its entirety is a (full stack) framework as well.

As for the third question: this is simple, the design pattern to use for MVC is MVC.