# Not being able to fetch an image from a directory using scriptlet in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a shopping page where I am showing different items available for purchase using the given JSP:

```
<%
String query ="select * from PRODUCT";

Connection con = ConnectDao.connect();
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
%> 

<%    while(rs.next()){%>

      <div class="grid1_of_4">
                 <img src="/uploads/<%=rs.getString(9) %>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                  </a>
                <h4><a href="#"><%=rs.getString(2) %></a></h4>                  
                 <div class="item_add"><span class="item_price"><h6>ONLY $<%=rs.getString(6) %></h6></span></div>
                <div class="item_add"><span class="item_price"><a href="#">add to cart</a></span></div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%} %>
```

I have the images stored in the uploads folder inside WebContents of my eclipse project folder.
And the corresponding image names are stored in the database(DB2) in the 9th column ( hence rs.getString(9)).

But still I am not being able to fetch the image.

Comment: so what is the `src` attribute of `img` tag showing?

Comment: should it be `<img src="uploads/filename.jpg" />` ? without the / before uploads

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan yeah i tried that also...i.e. using / before uploads

Comment: @Apostolos src attribute not being able to find the image in the given directory even though i have pictures in that directory

Comment: src will point to relative context path directory, not directory everywhere in your local drive. i guess you know that right?

Comment: could you please share more info? like the project structure. as @Apostolos asked what is the value  of the `src` attribute? moreover where is the start of the `</a>` tag? the one which points to your image.

Comment: @Apostolos yeah I know...thats why I used  src="uploads/filename.jpg"

Comment: if you inspect the element and hover it, you will see which is the full path of the image it is trying to display.

Comment: Yes and it directs to the same path as the image is lying in

Comment: Thanks guys...I got my problem....I had to refresh the WebContent folder of my project in eclipse and everything was working fine

Comment: It's nice you have found the problem, but I would like to remark, that you should not have business logic code (e.g. fetching from DB) in JSP. Better approach is to use [MVC pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354034/how-to-create-mvc-based-application-without-using-framework), or, at least, to put the logic aside to a Java class, and use JSP only to call the class methods and display results.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thank you. Point noted.