# Java Servlet Dispatcher Lifecycle

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, controller, requestdispatcher

I'm new to Java Web Development and I have a lot of confusion in my head. I'm trying to develop a small project in Java, but i don't know how the components of the MVC pattern should be connected.

I have a DAO that talk with the DB and is able to make normal CRUD operations pretty well. The DAO works with the package Model, that reflects my tables inside the DB. O the other side I have my JSP pages, inside WEB-INF folder.

I read this info tag about the servlets https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info and it doesn't works for me. As explained here:
[How to develop JSP/Servlets Web App using MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575471/how-to-develop-jsp-servlets-web-app-using-mvc-pattern)

The MVC pattern is composed with

1. **Model** (java classes / beans): that reflect the DB data (with properties, getter/setter methods).
2. **View** (JSP pages) here, my HTML, the presentation level.
3. **Controller** (The servlets) that map
   urls to JSP pages, right?

So the model works, the view work, the controller what should do? actually i get this error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /crm/hello.jsp type.
>   Status report message.
>   /crm/hello.jsp description. 
>   The requested resource is not available.

But the resource inside WEB-INF exists, the file hello.jsp, is there. Here the snippet of code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Preprocess request: we actually don't need to do any business stuff, so just display JSP.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Postprocess request: gather and validate submitted data and display result in same JSP.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

I'm using the @WebServlet notation, that should replace web.xml, right? I have also read the answer: [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications) and as explained there:

> Request (action) based MVC: this is the simplest to implement. The
>   (Business) Model works directly with HttpServletRequest and
>   HttpServletResponse objects. You have to gather, convert and validate
>   the request parameters (mostly) yourself. The View can be represented
>   by plain vanilla HTML/CSS/JS and it does not maintain state across
>   requests. This is how among others Spring MVC, Struts and Stripes
>   works.

I have to map each url to a JSP page and Servlet with a Request/Response inside or there's should be one Servlet that handle all request/response?
Where should i trace the session?
Where should i set the cookies?
Where should i do the business flow? For example insert the data from a web form to a db, or display the DB data to a JSP page?

I'm trying to connecting the dots, but someone missing. The problem is how the Model and View should talks with the controller? May you provide some example?

Comment: Forward to `/WEB-INF/hello.jsp` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried to put the page in /WEB-INF/ and it works. Before was setted in the same way, but the page was under Web Pages in NetBeans and not in /WEB-INF/. By the way, now it works, but all other questions are still unsolved.

Comment: Your other questions are quite broad. You should search for existing answers.

Comment: i'll try to search again and again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Controller works as a communicator between model and view. It updates the model based on view and it also updates the view based on controller.