# Calling other servlet methods from JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am making a servlet program. It is working fine, but now I am trying to make a method other than doGet or doPost that get called from JSP. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. If you want to have a single servlet which controls **all** requests and can invoke business actions depending on the request, then have a look at the [front controller pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060128/java-front-controller/2060842#2060842).

If you actually want to invoke utility methods (`public static` methods in a `public final` class) during display, then you can make use of [EL functions](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaiq) (something like as [JSTL functions](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)).

Comment: (+1) (well, actually you do access the `service(..)` method :) )

Comment: Or `doPut()`, `doTrace()`, etc.. But that's likely not what he's after :)

Comment: Then homegrow a framework with a front controller which does that. JSF for example is open source, check there how they did it.