# Starting a servlet from a main in java

Tags: servlets

How can you run a servlet on a server without putting it in the web.xml. I want to start a server from main and pass what servlet it should run
Thank you

Comment: Weird! Write a main method in Servlet and run it ! why need a server?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why does it have to be a servlet, and like Gopi mentioned, why even a server?

Comment: I'm working with MVC, the controller is needs to be able to start the server and run the servlet

Comment: I need a to be able to fill a queue of method invocations on the server. I either need and instance of a running server(I already posted this) or start it myself

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on the server you're using. If it's an embedded server like [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), then you can easily do that in flavor of a [`ServletHolder`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletHolder.html).

```
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()),"/*");
```

If it's other, then you need to consult the documentation of the server in question. It's usually not possible in non-embeddable servers like Tomcat, Glassfish and so on.

#### See also:

- [Embedding Jetty tutorial - ServletContext](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#ServletContext).

---

**Update**: as per the comments on your question, you're after all looking for a solution in the wrong direction. Reread the MVC pattern and more specifically the front controller pattern. You shouldn't use servlets as domain objects, but just simple constructable Java classes which don't extend `HttpServlet`. Finally you just end up with a single servlet which constructs/picks the right domain object based on the current request. You can find some insights and a basic kickoff example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060128/java-front-controller/2060842#2060842).

Comment: I'm using GWT's GAE, which is Jetty.

Comment: I know I should end up with one servlet. I didn't understand ur update? I cannot change the controller. It calls an instance of a view. This view needs to start the server(I can do this in GWT) I don't know how to access the java servlet running on it.